# Allow the user to change a JavaScript variable with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript variable:

```
var setClickTime = "2000";
```

I would like to give the user a choice of 2000 or 4000 based on their preference by clicking a button.

What is the best way to allow the user to change this variable? I have considered having two buttons one of which will have the class active when clicked. That would require me to set up an if / else statement to change the variable based on which button is active. But I am new to this and I do not know the best approach.

Comment: First make it work, then if it does, or not, you will have more information to decide if your choice was good.

Comment: dropdownlist, two buttons, radio buttons, label click, whatever

Comment: You should use radio buttons if the user is going to select either a value and intercept the selected option during click.

Comment: correction: you have a **javascript** variable - jquery is merely a javascript library (the j in jquery stands for javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your buttons IDs and bind listeners.

Say, you have two buttons `id="setTime2000"` and `id="setTime4000"`, then you just need:

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <button id="setTime2000">Set time as 2000</button>
    <button id="setTime4000">Set time as 4000</button>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready() {
    var mTime = 2000;  // set the default value of time

    $("#setTime2000").click(function () {
        mTime = 2000;
    }

    $("#setTime4000").click(function () {
        mTime = 4000;
    }

    // ... do something with the variable set
}
```

Comment: Ares Ou this is a very good answer. Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a button event listener to change it:

```
 <button id="changeBtn">4000</button>
```

JS

```
 var setClickTime = "2000";

 $("#changeBtn").click(function() {

    setClickTime = "4000";
 })
```

Comment: I really like this answer Cory. Very simple and reliable. I did not think to approach it this way.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a JavaScript variable, it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Then, if you want something easy, without dependencies. Here a simple example:

```js
var myValue = 2000;
updateOutput();

a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myValue = 2000;
  updateOutput()
});
b.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myValue = 4000;
  updateOutput()
});


function updateOutput() {
  output.value = myValue;
}
```

```html
<button id="a">2000</button>
<button id="b">4000</button>
<input readonly id="output">
```

Comment: You don't need 2 events. $('button').click(function(){ myValue = $(this).text(); }); would be much straight and better way.

Comment: Why should you rely on jQuery for a so simple task? And, by the way, jQuery, internally, creates two event listeners as well.

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer in pure javascript.

```
<button class='setTime'>
  2000
</button>

<button class='setTime'>
  4000
</button>
```

Pure Javascript:

```
var setClickTime = "";

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('setTime')
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  this.onclick = function setTime(event) {
    setClickTime = event.target.innerHTML;
    alert(setClickTime);
  }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1vy8ahp/

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple `radio` `buttons` for more options ( with same name attribute to group them ) and then just `delegate` or `bind` a `change` event on that group of `radios` `buttons` to get the selected value.

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2000">2000
<input type="radio" name="test" value="4000">4000
<script>
var setClickTime;
$('input:radio[name=test]').on('change',function()
{
  setClickTime = this.value;
});
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/71hgeqnb/1/

Comment: You should listen for the change event, not for the click

Comment: Yup. That would make more sense.